# How do I make a class conditionally return one of two other classes?

Tags: ruby

I have a design problem.

I'm writing a REST client in ruby.  For reasons beyond my control, it has to extend another gem that uses my networks zookeeper instance to do service lookup.  My client takes a user provided tier, and based on that value, queries the zookeeper registry for the appropriate service url.

The problem is that I also need to be able to run my client against a locally running version of the service under test.  When the service is running locally, zookeeper is obviously not involved, so I simply need to be able to make GET requests against the localhost resource url.

When a user instantiates my gem, they call something like:

```
client = MyRestClient.new(tier: :dev)
```

or in local mode

```
client = MyRestClient.new(tier: :local)
```

I would like to avoid conditionally hacking the constructor in MyRestClient (and all of the GET methods in MyRestClient) to alter requests based on `:local` vs. `:requests_via_the_zk_gem`.

I'm looking for an elegant and clean way to handle this situation in Ruby.

One thought was to create two client classes, one for `:local` and the other for `:not_local`.  But then I don't know how to provide a single gem interface that will return the correct client object.

If `MyClient` has a constructor that looks something like this:

```
class MyClient
  attr_reader :the_klass 
  def initialize(opts={})
    if opts[:tier] == :local
      @the_klass = LocalClass.new  
    else
      @the_klass = ZkClass.new
    end
    @the_klass
  end
end
```

then I end up with something like:

```
test = MyClient.new(tier: :local)
=> #<MyClient:0x007fe4d881ed58 @the_klass=#<LocalClass:0x007fe4d883afd0>>
test.class
=> MyClient
test.the_klass.class
=> LocalClass
```

those who then use my gem would have to make calls like:

```
@client = MyClient.new(tier: :local)
@client.the_klass.get
```

which doesn't seem right

I could use a module to return the appropriate class, but then I'm faced with the question of how to provide a single public interface for my gem.  I can't instantiate a module with .new.

My sense is that this is a common OO problem and I just haven't run into it yet.  It's also possible the answer is staring me in the face and I just haven't found it yet.

Most grateful for any help.

Comment: What you are looking for is called [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: instead of using `Class`, I think you could use `Module`, do `if opts[:tier] == :local then include LocalClientModule else include ZkModule end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is to pass the service into the client, something like:

```
class MyClient
  attr_reader :service

  def initialize(service)
    @service = service
  end

  def some_method
    service.some_method
  end
end
```

And create it with:

```
client = MyRestClient.new(LocalClass.new)
# or
client = MyRestClient.new(ZkClass.new)
```

You could move these two into class methods:

```
class MyClient

  self.local
    new(LocalClass.new)
  end

  self.dev
    new(ZkClass.new)
  end

end
```

And instead call:

```
client = MyRestClient.local
# or
client = MyRestClient.dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method_missing` to delegate from your client to the actual class.

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  @the_class.send(m, *args, &block)
end
```

So whenever a method gets called on your class that doesn't exist (like `get` in your example) it wil be called on `@the_class` instead.

It's good style to also define the corresponding `respond_to_missing?` btw:

```
def respond_to_missing?(m, include_private = false)
  @the_class.respond_to?(m)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The use case you are describing looks like a classic factory method use case.

The common solution for this is the create a method (*not* `new`) which returns the relevant class instance:

```
class MyClient

  def self.create_client(opts={})
    if opts[:tier] == :local
      LocalClass.new  
    else
      ZkClass.new
    end
  end
end
```

And now your usage is:

```
test = MyClient.create(tier: :local)
=> #<LocalClass:0x007fe4d881ed58>
test.class
=> LocalClass
```